# jQuery cached element

Tags: jquery, variables

I have a function that uses a cached element(el) to change the font size of **2 divs**. When the function executes I need to make sure the font is not too small or too large based on which div it is(`tagCommon` or `tagLatin`). So how can I determine in the function which element was passed to it via `el`?

I think I may be over thinking this or doing it wrong, it kinda feels like I am **hacking** it in...and usually when it feels like that there is something wrong.

```
var cb               = $('#tagCommon');
var lb               = $('#tagLatin'); 
changeFontSize(cb,1,'up');

function changeFontSize(el,amount,UporDown){
   var size = parseFloat($(el).css("font-size").replace(/px/, ""));
   // do some stuff here

   // ????????
   if(el == $('#tagCommon')) //check font size and alert if too small
   if(el == $('#tagLatin')) //check font size and alert if too small
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Todd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function changeFontSize(el,amount,UporDown){
   var size = parseFloat($(el).css("font-size").replace(/px/, "")),
       id = el.attr('id'); // or el[0].id

   if(id == 'tagCommon') //check font size and alert if too small
   if(id == 'tagLatin') //check font size and alert if too small

   // OR
   if(id == 'tagCommon')
   if(id == 'tagLatin')

   // OR
   if(el.is('#tagCommon'))
   if(el.is('#tagLatin'))
}
```

`.attr('id')` will retrieve the id and match with supplied one

`.is()` matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object. Return value boolean true/false.

Answer (score 3):

use jQuery [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element,
>   or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements
>   matches the given arguments.

```
if(el.is('#tagCommon'))
    {
      //  your code here
    }
```